# Should I enter Italy with an Italian passport?

Tags: uk, italy, uk-citizens, italian-citizens

I have Italian citizenship but don't have an Italian passport. I am going to go to Italy next summer for a few weeks. I am British. Is it okay to enter Italy on a foreign passport (especially an EU passport, for now) if you are an Italian citizen?

I am going to get a passport when the UK leaves the EU for easier travel to Europe but until then I don't see the point, unless I'll get in trouble at the Italian border control.

Comment: Aww, Colin Firth again...

Comment: If you are an italian citizen, you won't get in trouble for presenting it at the border.

Comment: @Paddez my question is presenting a British passport

Comment: You say you don't have an Italian passport, but what about an Italian ID card? They're valid (albeit discouraged by some countries) for travel anywhere in the EU, so Italy of all countries ought not to complain about using one.

Comment: Most countries seem not to have rules about their citizens entering with foreign passports.  Those that do generally have a degree of notoriety as a result.  If you can't find anything about Italy's rule, it's probably safe to assume it doesn't exist.

Comment: **don't have an Italian passport** -> do you mean you don't have Carta d'Identita' or any other document? Maybe I am missing something but how can you prove your Italian citizenship?

Comment: Can't answer I'm afraid, but you can always fly via another Schengen Country (Germany, France, Switzerland...) instead of directly to Italy, so you won't face Italian border control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of what Italian laws say on this subject, *in practice* you won't be questioned by border guards as all EU citizens either go through automatic passport controls or get a quick glance at their passport from the staff manning the border. In addition, Italy cannot deny you entry as you're both their citizen and an EU citizen, so at worst you'll receive a stern lecture at the border.

Relax and enjoy your holiday.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the problem. If you have a British passport that's it.

You don't need anything else to travel from UK to Italy.

It doesn't matter if you have italian citizenship or not, border police doesn't care as long as you have your British passport. (an italian ID card is a plus, but not required)

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/italy/entry-requirements